# How to understand the following context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I found a sentence: "The children had smeared peanut butter all over the sofa.".

Does "all" in the sentence mean all the sofa or all the butter?

Comment: It means _all the sofa_. More like all over the surface of the sofa, and perhaps it sides also.

Answer (score 2):

It's referring to the sofa. 'All over' is often used as a set phrase. One common meaning is 'covering a large amount of the surface area of something'. It's a somewhat hyperbolic phrase, since it does not literally mean 'all'. For example:

> There are crumbs all over the floor.  (=there are a lot of crumbs on the floor)

> There is graffiti all over the wall.  (=there is graffiti covering large parts of the wall)

> People all over the world are in lockdown. (=people in many parts of the world are in lockdown)

Comment: It could just be a small part of the sofa, but that would seem significant to a houseproud person, and justify saying "all over the sofa".

Comment: @Michael Harvey Maybe, but I would say that is less to do with language and more to do psychology. A standard interpretation of 'all over' would typically be more than a small degree of something.

Comment: My mother would say "We're being talked about all over the town" because one neighbour said something about her to another.

Comment: Of course there are ironic uses (as with any phrase), but are you suggesting that “all over” means something like “a lot but concentrated in a small area”?

Comment: I am suggesting that "all over" can be a pretty flexible concept, especially with peanut butter on a nice and expensive sofa.